# Mongo java driver lookup with inner pipeline

Tags: java, mongodb, lookup, pipeline, aggregation

The newest version (3.6) of the Mongo server introduced a nice feature in the `$lookup` stage of aggregations. Now, the operator takes a pipeline as an argument to run on the collection to join (as explained [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#join-conditions-and-uncorrelated-sub-queries)), which, for example, would allow to filter the documents that will be joined before joining.
Is there any way to make use of it in the java driver? I've looked through the driver's [reference](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/builders/aggregation/#lookup) and [API](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.6/javadoc/com/mongodb/client/model/Aggregates.html) documentation and didn't find anything. Is there something I'm missing or is it not implemented yet?

Answer (score 2):

You can use version `3.7.0-SNAPSHOT` of the library.

See https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-java-driver/pull/434/files#diff-63c7b578add7f32066a07ad92de3fea2R275

Comment: I already solved this issue by building an ArrayList<org.bson.Document> manually and passing it to another '$lookup' Document. What you showed does seem to solve it, but since v3.7 isn't out yet, I won't mark your answer as accepted.